# Mysql SELECT FOR UPDATE - strange issue

Tags: mysql, locking, blocking

I have a strange issue (at least for me :)) with the MySQL's locking facility.

I have a table:

```
create table `test` (  
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

With this data:

> +----+
>   | id |
>   +----+
>   |  3 |
>   |  4 |
>   |  5 |
>   |  6 |
>   |  7 |
>   |  8 |
>   | 10 |
>   | 11 |
>   | 12 |
>   +----+

Now I have 2 clients with these commands executed at the beginning:

> set autocommit=0;
>   set session transaction isolation level serializable;
>   begin;

Now the most interesting part. The first client executes this query: (makes an intent to insert a row with id equal to 9)

> SELECT * from test where id = 9 FOR UPDATE;
>   Empty set (0.00 sec)

Then the second client does the same:

> SELECT * from test where id = 9 FOR UPDATE;
>   Empty set (0.00 sec)

My question is: Why the second client does not block ? An exclusive gap lock should have been set by the first query because FOR UPDATE have been used and the second client should block.

If I am wrong, could somebody tell me how to do it correctly ?

The MySql version I use is: 5.1.37-1ubuntu5.1

Comment: It doesn't block because you have successfully locked **zero** rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because at that time, it's safe to return the (empty) result - there's no lock to set for the record with id=9 as that doesn't exist and thus it cannot be updated - I don't think you can rely on innodb setting a read locks in such a case. It should set a write lock on id=9 though.

If at a later time, one of the transactions do update the table, and touch the same data as another transaction - the update would likely block in one of the transactions and later on fail if the other transaction commited that data. It's perfectly normal for transactions to fail in scenarios like this - leaving you to handle it - which usually is a matter of retrying the transaction.

If there were a record with id=9 you'd probably see the 2. `select` block until the first transaction is finished, as now there is a record that have to be read locked in case the first transaction decides to update that row.

Comment: Yes, if there is a record with id=9 the 2nd select blocks. So how should I "reserve" the id 9?
I have this problem because I am storing some relation between pairs of objects and I want only one row for given pair of objects.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do. Will one of your transactions create id=9 ? in which case the other transaction will fail/get rolled back.

Comment: I am trying to implement something like this in Java:

if (!rowExists(9)) {
createRowWithId(9);
} else {
return "Error";
} 

And I am getting duplicated ids...

Comment: For that case, It seems an unique constraint on the id should take care of it. For the more general case, it might be more complicated. Though you could do if (rowsWithId(9) == 1) { createRowWithId(9); if (rowsWithId(9) > 1) rollback(); } , the transactions would ensure only one many concurrent ones does the rollback.

Comment: I have the same problem, except that I can't use the unique key trick.  Any ideas?

Comment: In the general case, this seems to be precisely what serializable transactions are made for. Call `start transaction` before each select, and MySQL will ensure that no transaction sees one table state in `select` and overwrites a different one in `update`. (For more detail, see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability).)

Answer (score -1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: But I don't want to lock the whole table. It will be very slow then.